# Align marginpar with top of current paragraph

Tags: bibliographies, vertical-alignment, marginpar, back-referencing

I am using `\usepackage{backref}` to create a back reference in my bibliography. That part is working fine. I am now attempting to use `\marginpar` to have those references show in the margin, like so: [image: Bibliography with backreferences in the margin]

That, too, works pretty much as expected, with one big exception: as you can see, the references are aligned with the bottom of the entry. Is there a way to have them align with the top? I could simply push then up a few lines with `\vspace{}`, I suppose, but there is no way to know how many lines either the main entry or the backreferences will be taking.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
\leavemode
    \marginpar{
        \raggedright 
        \scriptsize S.~#2
              }
```

Comment: where is the promised MWE.  Or better yet the working solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't give an MWE as a starting point, so I did something here with the article class to show how a margin note can be bottom justified.

I realize this isn't exactly what you asked, but without knowing more about how to even create what you showed in your example, I thought, with the black bar already at the bottom of the entry), that this might be a suitable option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand*\mnote[2]{%
  \if l#1\reversemarginpar\fi%
  \if r#1\normalmarginpar\fi%
  \savestack{\mybox}{\parbox[b]{1.8cm}{\raggedright\scriptsize#2}}%
  \marginpar{\belowbaseline[-\ht\myboxcontent]{\mybox}}%
}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\mnote{l}{some text for the mnote box}

\lipsum*[2]\mnote{r}{Here is another marginnote on the right}

\lipsum*[2]\mnote{r}{another mnote box test testing the right side}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I'll have to study the code a bit closer. Would top-justification be just as easy?

Comment: @ingmar It can be justified in any way.  What I don't know (preventing me from a fuller answer) is whether the `backref` package or you the user control where the `\marginpar` is invoked.  Clearly, if you control it, it could be invoked at the beginning of the reference, rather than at the end, as it appears now.  However, what would happen to that black bar, I don't have a clue (I'm presuming the package did that, not you).  It would be helpful if you provided a small, fully working example, starting with `\documentclass`.

Comment: `\marginpar` is invoked by `backref` (actually, I am simply using `\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4] {}`. That black bar is manually drawn on the screenshot, in a rather clumsy attempt to highlight the alignment. It does not appear in the document.

Comment: Yes, I'll provide an MWE shortly. Thanks for now.

Comment: @ingmar, Too bad... I kind of liked the black bar, and it would fit well the solution I proposed above :^)

Comment: after playing around with your code some more, this works perfectly. Bottom-justification works good, in fact it's probably the best solution. Happy camper here, marking your answer as the solution. Thanks a lot!